# Laravel - Too few arguments to function (Insert data)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in really need of help as I can't figure out what's the problem and have browsed for answers unsuccessfully.

I need to insert data about an employee from a view which should be pretty simple. So i have two tables - ''Department'' and ''Employees''. When I open the view ''Department'' it shows each department and I can further choose one of the departments and see all of the employees that work in that department, I can delete the employees. Everything works to this point. But when I want to add an employee it displays the error - Too few arguments (...) .

**Routes**

```
Route::get('department/', 'DepartmentController@index');

Route::get('department/delete/{id}','DepartmentController@destroy');

Route::get('employee/new/{id}', 'EmployeeController@new');

Route::get('employee/insert/{id}', 'EmployeeController@store');

Route::get('employee/{id}', 'EmployeeController@index');
```

**EmployeeController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Employee;
use App\Department;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class EmployeeController extends Controller
  {
    public function index($department_id){
       $employees=Employee::where('department_id','=',$department_id)->get();
       return view('employees' ['department_id'=>$department_id,'employees'=>$employees]);
  }

    public function new ($department_id){
       $departments=Department::where('department_id','=',$department_id)->get();       
       return view('employee_new',['department_id'=>$department_id,'department_name'=>$departments[0]->department_name]);
  }
    public function store( $id, $name, $surname, $email, $phone){
     $employee = new Employee;

     $employee->employee_name = $name;
     $employee->employee_surname = $surname;
     $employee->employee_email = $email;
     $employee->employee_phone = $phone;
     $employee->department_id = $id;

     $employee->save();
  }
```

**Employee Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model{

protected $table = 'employees';

   public function department() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Department');
 }
}
```

**employee_new.blade (view)**

```
Adding a new employee for <b>{{ $department_name }}</b> department:
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Employee Name<td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="employee_name"></td>

    <td>Employee Surname<td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="employee_surname"></td>

    <td>Employee Email<td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="employee_email"></td>

    <td>Employee Phone number<td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="employee_phone"></td>


    <td><input type="button" value="add" onclick="addEmployee()"></td>

</tr>

</table>
<script>
    function addEmployee() {    
        window.location.href="/employee/insert/"+{{$department_id}};          
    }
</script>
```

**Error line**

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \
 FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
 Too few arguments to function 
 App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 5 expected
```

Comment: Where is the error line?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts sorry, just updated the post with the error line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than one issues on your code, I will point them one by one:

1. You don't have a form tag with action
2. You are calling the function with 1 argument (in the javascript) but
   it expects 5 arguments ( $id, $name, $surname, $email, $phone )
3. Route that inserts something to the database needs to be post not
   get
4. You have to be careful when passing data to database as get
   parameters because it is very unsecure

I will provide you with a simple example so you can grab the essence

Your view (lets suppose that is called new-user.blade.php):

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('saveData') }}">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Your controller (with saveData method) - let's suppose that your controller is called UserController

Load add new user form method:

```
public function userForm()
{
return view('new-user');
}
```

Save data to the database:

```
public function saveData(Request $request)
{
$user = new User;
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->save();

// or User::create($request->all());

return view('view-name')->with('status', 'User was saved!');
}
```

Your routes (on web.php file)

`Route::get('/new-user', 'UserController@userForm');` // to load the form

`Route::post('/create-user', 'UserController@saveData')->name('saveData');` // to save data to the dabase

Comment: Thank you so much, I also added `protected $fillable = [ 'all_of_the_necessary_table_columns' ];` in the user model file and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to method arguments.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
     $employee = new Employee;
     $employee->employee_name = $request->employee_name;
     $employee->employee_surname = $request->employee_surname;
     $employee->employee_email = $request->employee_email;
     $employee->employee_phone = $request->employee_phone;
     $employee->department_id = $id;
     $employee->save();
}
```

Also input tags do not have a name attribute.

Comment: now it shows this error: ` Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000)
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'employee_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `employees` (`employee_name`, `employee_surname`, `employee_email`, `employee_phone`, `department_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , 1, 2018-06-17 16:55:19, 2018-06-17 16:55:19)) `

Comment: html input tags does not have name attrbiute

Comment: not sure what you mean. Could you show what the input tag should look like?

Comment: `<input type="text" id="employee_name" name="employee_name">` do this for all input tags

Comment: oh ok, i did that but it shows the same error - Column 'employee_name' cannot be null

Comment: you should fill all fields before submit do not leave empty fields

Comment: i did that also

Comment: your html is not complete. you should wrap form elements into `<form>` tag with action and method attributes.

Comment: ok, but one last question- what should i put in as action if i need to it be ` "/employee/insert/"+{{$department_id}} ` ?

Comment: route to store method. first add route on web.php then add `{{route()}}` to store method.